# Login error on joomla 3.4.1

Tags: joomla-3.x, login

I have problem with my Joomla 3.4.1. Login generally works fine, but sometimes when a user logs-out and want to login again, I get this strange error.

I don't even know what this is says :

The URL which im getting the error is :
http://bajeman.com/login-form?task=user.login

And the error looks like this :
[image: Strange error on login]

My language setting in Joomla :
Could be this cause of the problem ?
My language is persian and its not listed in content page 
[image]

[image: login for redirections]

Comment: I could be wrong, but it might be due to incorrect character encoding as it's a Persian website. Are you using the default Joomla login module/component or a 3rd party one?

Comment: @Lodder i use default login mudule and yes its a persian website ? how can i fix encoding ?

Comment: Check that your database tables are set to `utf8_general` encoding. Like I said though, I could be wrong, maybe someone else might be able to give a more definitive answer

Comment: @Lodder i uploaded the language section of my Joomla can this be a cause of the problem ? should i add Farsi manually ?

Comment: Try installing the Persian language. From the page in your screenshot, click on "Install Language". But also check the database tables for the encoding type

Comment: After trying to re-login and you get this message: What happens if you just refresh the page, or simply navigate back to a normal page of your site? Does the system sees you a loggen in user?

Comment: @Lodder there is no persian in the list of content languages

Comment: @FFrewin it occurring after to login and logout and after refresh nothing changes same error .no im not logged in after navigation to my home page

Comment: Regarding the issue itself, If I have to guess about what is the error message it is showing on re-login, I would say it might be about invalid token. The language should not be the cause of the re-login issue. I guess it is a different issue, which it's just manifests itself on your re-login issue.

Comment: Maybe create a redirection for the log-out - so the users will return either to home page, or back to the login form as you have it specified: http://bajeman.com/login-form

Comment: @FFrewin i redirected both login and logout to / , but i cant find them :| to show you it was in the profile module i think

Comment: So the redirection you set doesn't work? Regarding the log-out redirection, you need it to specify it at exit place, meaning where your users logout. For example, this could be the bajeman.com/login-form menu item.

Comment: @FFrewin i added login for redirection img

Comment: @Lodder content language and utf8 database is fixed but nothing happens database was already utf8

Comment: @FFrewin i changed the page settings to UTF8 and error is wrong input ?

Answer (score 1):

You can give the language manually in content page.

Goto backend -> Extension -> Language manager -> Content -> New -> Here you can set the valid title and language tag then click save.